# Django migrations issues with foreign dependency

Tags: django, jenkins, django-migrations

I am trying to deal with an "it works on my machine" type of problem. I have a django project using jenkins which fails on migrations. The step is triggered with this command: `python manage.py test -v 2 --noinput` and there goes traceback:

```
  Applying gloodny.0020_auto_20180314_1338... OK
  Applying openinghours.0001_initial... OK
  Applying payu_payment.0002_auto_20171222_1407... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/papuportal/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/papuportal/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/papuportal/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 30, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/papuportal/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/papuportal/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 74, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/papuportal/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/papuportal/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 90, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/papuportal/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 532, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/papuportal/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 482, in setup_databases
    self.parallel, **kwargs
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/papuportal/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 726, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get("TEST", {}).get("SERIALIZE", True),
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/papuportal/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 78, in create_test_db
    self.connection._test_serialized_contents = self.serialize_db_to_string()
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/papuportal/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 122, in serialize_db_to_string
    serializers.serialize("json", get_objects(), indent=None, stream=out)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/papuportal/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 129, in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/papuportal/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 79, in serialize
    for count, obj in enumerate(queryset, start=1):
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/papuportal/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 118, in get_objects
    for obj in queryset.iterator():
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/papuportal/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 52, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/papuportal/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 848, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/papuportal/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/papuportal/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/papuportal/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "openinghours_company" does not exist
LINE 1: ...mpany"."slug", "openinghours_company"."logo" FROM "openingho...
```

This is caused by [openinghours django library](https://github.com/arteria/django-openinghours).

Problem I am facing is more complicated since locally those migrations run without error:

```
  Applying gloodny.0020_auto_20180314_1338... OK
  Applying gloodny.0021_auto_20180320_1426... OK
  Applying gloodny.0022_auto_20180320_1550... OK
  Applying openinghours.0001_initial... OK
  Applying openinghours.0002_auto_20180320_1426... OK
  Applying payu_payment.0002_auto_20171222_1407... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
  Applying thumbnail.0001_initial... OK
```

I have set `OPENINGHOURS_PREMISES_MODEL` settings variable to a model I actually have, I have also tried to add a dependency:

```
dependencies = [
         ('payu_payment', '0001_initial'),
         ('openinghours', '0002_auto_20180320_1426'),
     ]
```

but then the build failed with this error:

> Migration payu_payment.0002_auto_20171222_1407 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node (u'openinghours', u'0002_auto_20180320_1426')

How can I fix those migrations?

**EDIT** I fixed a typo pointed out in comments, but now I can run tests with command mentioned above locally and on jenkins I get the same error.

Comment: @Alasdair it was my typo, but after fixing it I am able to run tests locally and get same error on jenkins

Comment: I mean without dot: `Migration payu_payment.0002_auto_20171222_1407 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node (u'openinghours', u'0002_auto_20180320_1426')`

Comment: That migration `0002_auto_20180320_1426` doesn't exist in the openinghours repo you linked to. What does it do? How was it created? How do you expect Jenkins to be able to access it?

Comment: It's version I see in my `site-packages`. When I changed to `(u'openinghours', u'0002_auto_20170915_0912')` to match version in the linked repo same problem occurrs.

Comment: Have you checked that migration exists on Jenkins?

Comment: Now yes. No 0002 migration exists there. I'll investigate jenkins configuration further. Thanks for hints.